# Python error for loop

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and Python!

```
for i in range(0.6):
print(i)
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in range(0.6):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range takes in two values, not a single float!

It should be

```
for i in range(0,6):
    print(i)
```

this would give you

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

or just `range(6)`

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant this:

```
for i in range(0,6):
    print(i)
```

You need to change period to comma.  Also, you need to indent the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mistyped, and meant to put a comma instead of a dot:

```
for n in range(0,6):
    print(n)
```

actually, the '0' in **range()** is not even needed, you can also do this, and it will print the same thing:

```
for n in range(6):
    print(n)
```

both would output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```